# Nginx location block specific file

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx location blocks:

```
location /publish/domain.io.php {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
}

location ~\.php {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

The problem is that the location block `/publish/domain.io.php` does not seem to be executing. I can call the php script `domain.io.php` from any host.

Ideas? Thanks much.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `=` location prefix to determine exact match. As it is written in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location): "If an exact match is found, the search terminates."

So, your location should look like:

```
location = /publish/domain.io.php {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;              # Gives 403
}
```

or

```
location = /publish/domain.io.php {
  internal;              # Gives 404
}
```